# How to invoke editrules through custom button in my jqGrid or sjg:grid

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid, struts2

We are using Struts2-jQuery Grid (sjg:grid) which is built on top of jqGrid

We have added editrules defined in my gridcolumn and they are getting invoked when i click on the 'Save' button that comes with the grid. But, we have defined a custom button in the NavBar/ToolBar of the grid for the 'Save operation'.

**How can i invoke the rules defined (via EditRules) for a gridcolumn when user clicks on our custom button ?**

**Update (to provide more details & sample code):**

The jQGrid seems to have custom "edittype" and "editrules" options .. [reference url](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom)

we have defined similar custom editrules for our grid column as below.

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="customType" index="customType" title="customType"
editable="false" edittype="custom" editrules="{custom:true, custom_func:mypricecheck}"></sjg:gridColumn>
```

and the javascript function is defined as below in the same JSP page

```
function mypricecheck(value, colname) {
alert('Calling custom validation');
if (value < 0 || value >20) 
  return [false,"Please enter value between 0 and 20"];
else 
  return [true,""];
}
```

we added a custom button in our sjg:grid using this additional attribute in my sjg:grid tag.

```
navigatorExtraButtons="{
                           SaveAll:{
                                     title:'Save All',
                                     onclick:function(){fnSaveAll()}
                                   }
                         };
```

now on click of this custom button, i want to invoke the the editrules validation from my fnSaveAll() javascript function. The editrules validation is getting automatically called when i click on the default 'Save' button that comes with the grid.

If i know how it's internally invoking, then i can invoke through the same way from my custom button.

Comment: @Piyush Sardana .. sorry for the inconvenience.. i have now added code snippets in reference to my question.

Comment: @Uchenna Nwanyanwu .. sorry for the inconvenience.. i have now added code snippets in reference to my question.